# PHP 7.1 on Apache 2.4.27 Not working

Tags: php, apache

I've been running Apache 2.4.27 on Ubuntu 17.10 for a few months without issue.  Today I downloaded and installed PHP 7.1, enabled the mod and restarted the Apache sevrer. Created a php info script and when I pulled it up in the browser the page was blank.  I checked that the module was, indeed, enabled in Apache and I am not getting errors in the Apache error log.  Google search of the problem shows me all the ways to install the PHP package (which I believe was done correctly) but none show me how to troubleshoot this issue.  Can someone please hold my hand and help me through what I am possibly missing?

Comment: Hm, strange because usually if you install PHP wrong you must see your code inside .php file in the browser. Maybe you can give me URL to instruction so I will try to reproduce your steps

Comment: Igor, my apologies but I do not understand what you are asking for.  Also, according to the chrome developer window, the call is being made to the php file and the response is the code inside the file, but nothing is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Hi there, at least `php -v` at terminal does it work?

Comment: Hey guys, the issue was with my php file.  had <? instead of <?php.  Obvious oversight on my part.  Thanks for your responses!